# What happens to waiting thread if notify() is not called?

Tags: java, multithreading

What happens to waiting thread if notify() is not called? Is this spurious wakeup?

Comment: You mean thread is waking up without notify?

Comment: Yes I have called wait but didn't have coded to notify .

Comment: spurious wakeups are very rare and unlikely to happen. Are you using `notifyAll()` ?

Comment: If you want to know what happened to a particular piece of code with `wait()` in it, you should post the code. Spurious wakeups are rare, and not likely to repeat consistently if you run the program again. So if you can reproduce this problem, it is probably not a suprious wakeup.

Comment: if you are using overloaded method of `wait()` then that Thread can wake up. other than that its rare case!

Answer (score 11):

If a *waiting* `Thread` is not *notified* by calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the object the said thread is waiting on, then any one of the following may happen:

- the `Thread` keeps waiting in the object's *wait pool*
- the `Thread` becomes *runnable* if a timeout was specified and the time elapses
- the `Thread` gets *interrupted* and becomes *runnable* again
- the `Thread` wakes up for **no** reason at all i.e. it was neither *notified* nor *interrupted*

The last case is known as a *spurious wake-up* and is one of the reasons why upon wake-up a `Thread` should always check whether the condition it was waiting for is true or not. If not, the `Thread` should call and go `wait()` again.